# Did Jacob do right by Essau?

Tags: esav, jacob

When a family member is on the brink of death and is desperate for food and drink it seems rather harsh to extort his birth-right from him. I would just share my food with the person if they are that famished. This is a brother as well.

I wonder if the moral implications of this story has been discussed somewhere? Does not strike me as a particularly nice thing to do to family.

Comment: "_When a family member is on the brink of death_ ...". Despite [Essau's protestation to that effect](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.25.32?lang=bi&lang2=en), the Bible's narrator says he was [עיף](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.25.29?lang=bi&lookup=%DBible's7%A2%D6%B8%D7%99%D6%B5%D6%BD%D7%A3&with=Lexicon&lang2=en) (_ayef_). Modern Hebrew 'עיף' means 'tired'. Bible translators translate it as: famished, weary, faint, exhausted, hungry, or some combination of the above. That doesn't sound like he was on the brink of death to me.

Comment: If you read the story carefully, Jacob offered Esau bread as well as the pottage Esau asked for. Esau could have just taken the bread or other food. He specifically wanted the pottage.

Comment: You've probably never lived in a family where different siblings have different rights.

Comment: I wonder if anyone else will attempt to answer the question as stated, or if all the other answers will be some form of "Esau had it coming."

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how the story is  understood as Esau being on brink of death  and so  desperate for food but either way there was no taking advantage of him in the story.

As the story continues

וְיַֽעֲקֹ֞ב נָתַ֣ן לְעֵשָׂ֗ו לֶ֚חֶם וּנְזִ֣יד עֲדָשִׁ֔ים וַיֹּ֣אכַל וַיֵּ֔שְׁתְּ וַיָּ֖קָם וַיֵּלַ֑ךְ וַיִּ֥בֶז עֵשָׂ֖ו אֶת־הַבְּכֹרָֽה

*And Jacob gave Esau bread and a pottage of lentils, and he ate and drank got up and   left, and Esau disgraced the birthright of the being the eldest son*

The commentators say that he gave Esau bread first even though that hadn't been a part of the deal so that Esau would be of sound mind when receiving the lentils. As the verse continues even when Esau was fully satiated he continued to disgrace the value of the birth right so  there was no taking advantage. Yaakov  bought something Esau clearly did not value at the time.

Comment: You answered the question of did Esau value the birthright. You did not answer the question of did Jacob do right by Esau.

Comment: @Aaron This all depends on what one defines as "right". If one defines "right" as Jacob not having the birthright regardless of how it came about, then I guess yeah, Jacob did not do "right" (and there is no possible answer that would satisfy your definition of "right"). But what this answer explains is that Esau was not in dire danger or being taken advantage of, and of sound mind and body to make a valid sale. Once we cross that hurdle, why wouldn't Jacob's actions be "right" for doing a legitimate transaction?

Comment: @Salmononius2 This isn't about whether the sale was valid. But whether Jacob did right by his brother in the transaction. Because what it looks like is Jacob literally offers almost nothing for something of great value. It is up to Esau to accept, and I'm not here to argue the validity of the sale. I'm arguing whether Esau would walk away from the transaction saying "My brother did right by me." which is actually the question

Answer (score -3):

As others have and will doubtless continue to point out, it's very unlikely Esau was on the point of dying. He's clearly exaggerating how tired/hungry he is. So you won't find many people who would agree with you that Jacob extorted Esau.

Having said that, you are asking if Jacob did right by Esau. And to do right by someone is defined as: "To do right by means to treat someone in an ethical, moral, or honorable fashion. Do right by implies that one is making up for past wrongs inflicted on that person. Do right by is an idiom, related terms are did right by, does right by and doing right by." Based on this standard I can't say Jacob did right by Esau in the story you are discussing.

Imagine instead of a birthright, we were discussing Esau's car that he got from Isaac since he was the first born/oldest. Imagine Esau is really not responsible with the car, and isn't driving Jacob around like he should have been. Now imagine you're father Isaac and you hear that Esau sold his car to Jacob for a pot of soup. You would be disappointed in Esau for having sold something so valuable for something so trivial. And you would also be disappointed in Jacob for having ripped off his brother by even making such an offer. To do right by someone is to act fairly, which means regardless of what Esau did with the car, Jacob should have offered something of more fair value. But Jacob didn't do that, he offered something of trivial value, knowing how much Esau didn't value the car, and took advantage of the situation. And while this isn't extortion, it's far from treating someone in a fair and just way. And in Genesis 27 Jacob does even worse things to his brother and his father, where he impersonates his brother in order to take a blessing meant for his brother.

While there are commentators and Rabbi's who justify the actions of Jacob stealing the birthright from Esau in the story you mention, I find their justifications to be hollow. Because all their apologetics boil down to "Esau didn't value the birthright, so it wasn't so bad that Jacob tried to buy it for an unfair price." The justifications for Jacob impersonating Esau also boil down to "Esau wouldn't have done good things with the blessing and so of course it was better for Jacob to steal it!" Followed by "And Isaac gave Jacob another blessing so clearly it was the right thing!" These apologists seem to forget that Jacob and Rivkah are literally telling their son to go into exile because of what he did. They aren't even trying to stop Esau from taking revenge, because they know that Esau is ***justified*** in wanting revenge. And the Torah itself does not appear to view Jacob as the righteous victim, because Jacob is tricked in a similar way by Laban and Leah. Leah under Laban's knowledge impersonated her sister while it was dark and Jacob could not see. It's the exact same situation except the genders are switched.

But despite all that, and possibly ***because*** all that, I argue that Jacob does right by Esau in the end. Not only that, but Esau did right by Jacob by forgiving his brother despite what Jacob did to him as a youth.

Despite Jacob supposedly "buying" the birthright, we see no evidence that the birthright was actually given to Jacob by Isaac in the Torah. Instead we find that Jacob is literally exiled for the entirety of Esau's life, and we hear no mention of a birthright being passed down. What we do see is that while Jacob has made a decent living and built a little family, Esau is wealthy enough to basically have his own army. So either God blessed Esau in wealth way more than Jacob, or Esau actually received financial assistance from Isaac in a way that Jacob did not since Jacob was in exile. Furthermore, while Isaac seems to believe that once a blessing is said it can't be changed or taken away, the Torah doesn't seem to believe that, at least not in an immediate literal way, and Jacob doesn't seem to believe that either.

Isaac blesses Jacob as follows:

Genesis 27:29, 27:39

> **יַֽעַבְד֣וּךָ** עַמִּ֗ים (וישתחו) [וְיִֽשְׁתַּחֲו֤וּ] לְךָ֙ לְאֻמִּ֔ים
> הֱוֵ֤ה גְבִיר֙ לְאַחֶ֔יךָ וְיִשְׁתַּחֲו֥וּ לְךָ֖ בְּנֵ֣י אִמֶּ֑ךָ
> אֹרְרֶ֣יךָ אָר֔וּר וּֽמְבָרְכֶ֖יךָ בָּרֽוּךְ׃
>
> Let peoples serve you, And nations bow to you; Be master over your
> brothers, And let your mother’s sons bow to you. Cursed be they who
> curse you, Blessed they who bless you.”
>
> וַיַּ֨עַן יִצְחָ֜ק וַיֹּ֣אמֶר לְעֵשָׂ֗ו הֵ֣ן גְּבִ֞יר שַׂמְתִּ֥יו
> לָךְ֙ וְאֶת־כׇּל־אֶחָ֗יו נָתַ֤תִּי לוֹ֙ **לַעֲבָדִ֔ים** וְדָגָ֥ן
> וְתִירֹ֖שׁ סְמַכְתִּ֑יו וּלְכָ֣ה אֵפ֔וֹא מָ֥ה אֶֽעֱשֶׂ֖ה בְּנִֽי׃
>
> Isaac answered, saying to Esau, “But I have made him master over you:
> I have given him all his brothers for servants, and sustained him with
> grain and wine. What, then, can I still do for you, my son?”

Isaac had blessed Jacob saying that his brother(s) would serve him, and it appears Isaac believes this fate cannot be changed. But the Torah shows zero examples of Esau serving Jacob, Esau bowing to Jacob, and Jacob never calls Esau his servant. In fact, Jacob does right by Esau by telling him that he has not accepted the blessing or Esau's servitude, and Jacob is in fact willing to offer his servitude to Esau, hinting that the proper owner of the blessing is Esau.

Genesis 33:5

וַיִּשָּׂ֣א אֶת־עֵינָ֗יו וַיַּ֤רְא אֶת־הַנָּשִׁים֙ וְאֶת־הַיְלָדִ֔ים וַיֹּ֖אמֶר מִי־אֵ֣לֶּה לָּ֑ךְ וַיֹּאמַ֕ר הַיְלָדִ֕ים אֲשֶׁר־חָנַ֥ן אֱלֹהִ֖ים אֶת־**עַבְדֶּֽךָ**׃

Looking about, he [Esau] saw the women and the children. “Who,” he asked, “are these with you?” He [Jacob] answered, “The children with whom God has favored **your servant.**”

Instead of Jacob being haughty and calling Esau his servant, Jacob calls himself Esau's servant. Not only that, Jacob's entire family bows low to Esau, and Jacob implies that all he has belongs to his brother Esau. And because Jacob is offering his servitude to Esau, a complete reversal of the blessing he stole, Esau tells Jacob to keep everything of his, because Esau has enough.

Genesis 33:8-9

> וַיֹּ֕אמֶר מִ֥י לְךָ֛ כׇּל־הַמַּחֲנֶ֥ה הַזֶּ֖ה אֲשֶׁ֣ר פָּגָ֑שְׁתִּי
> וַיֹּ֕אמֶר לִמְצֹא־חֵ֖ן בְּעֵינֵ֥י אֲדֹנִֽי׃
>
> And he [Esau] asked, “What do you mean by all this company which I
> have met?” He [Jacob] answered, “To gain my lord’s favor.”
>
> וַיֹּ֥אמֶר עֵשָׂ֖ו יֶשׁ־לִ֣י רָ֑ב אָחִ֕י יְהִ֥י לְךָ֖ אֲשֶׁר־לָֽךְ׃
>
> Esau said, “I have enough, my brother; let what you have remain
> yours.”

The Torah does not hide the sins of our ancestors. We are meant to learn from imperfect people, because we are all imperfect ourselves. And we learn the great merit of Jacob because after having so much taken from him by his uncle, he understood he had much to apologize and offer to his brother. Only at that point did Jacob do right by his brother, and did his brother do right by him.

Comment: "_While there are commentators and Rabbi's who justify the actions of Jacob stealing the birthright from Esau in the story you mention, I find their justifications to be hollow_". Who, for instance? Where? What justification?

Comment: "... _and eventually impersonate and trick the parents when they are old and blind, they will say no_". (1) The Question isn't asking about that. (2) Although Isaac trembled greatly over what had happened, he tells Esau that Jacob shall remain blessed, and later even gives Jacob yet another blessing, when sending him off to live with Lavan. Is that what a father does, when his favorite son is wronged?

Comment: "very few parents would encourage one of their sons take the actions of Jacob in the way he went about it."... I mean, I can quite easily think of one parent who encouraged her son to take the actions of Jacob in the way he went about it...

Comment: @TamirEvan "and later even gives Jacob yet another blessing, when sending him off to live with Lavan. Is that what a father does, when his favorite son is wronged?" Sure it is. Isaac is sending Jacob into literal exile, because of what Jacob did, for supposedly the remainder of Esau's life, which means Isaac knows he may never see Jacob again. Any father would make a blessing. Just think of a father who is sending one son to prison for stealing the other son's car. The father may be pissed, but he may still support the son going to prison and bless him out of fear he may never come back

Comment: @Salmononius2 So if instead of a birthright, we were talking about a car or a very valuable camel. You'd still encourage your son to do what Jacob did?

Comment: I'd downvote a second time if I could. You're cherry picking and twisting words to fit your bias. There are many issues with your answer, but I'll stick to what fits in one comment: "Rivkah [is] literally telling [her] son to go into exile because of what he did" - Rivkah is the one who created the plan. "Isaac had blessed [...] that his brother(s) would serve him" - the fact that you had to add a parenthesis to explain a plural wording shows that you know your explanation is wrong. Clearly this is a future blessing, so the fact that in ~30 years it hadn't been fulfilled doesn't invalidate it.

Comment: @Salmononius2 And Rivkah is the one who says let the sin be on her, because she knows its wrong. The OP's question is whether Jacob did right by Esau. And all you can muster is Esau had it coming. If you want to post an answer showing how Jacob did right by Esau, then go ahead. I'll look forward to reading it. But also, Isaac interprets his own prophecy in the present tense, so why are you mad at me? "וַיַּ֨עַן יִצְחָ֜ק וַיֹּ֣אמֶר לְעֵשָׂ֗ו הֵ֣ן גְּבִ֞יר שַׂמְתִּ֥יו לָךְ֙" . Clearly Isaac doesn't view this as a future only prophecy. And... I never added parenthesis for plural wording??

Comment: @Aaron 1: "And Rivkah is the one who says let the sin be on her" False, she says let the _curse_ be upon her, nothing about sin, in response to Jacob expressing concern that he will receive a curse instead of a blessing. 2: There is no answer that can satisfactorily explain this as "right" to you because you have already concluded that it is "wrong". 3: This is a copy paste of your answer where the parenthesis is added to the "s" in brothers to make it look singular (first line after your first block quote): "Isaac had blessed Jacob saying that his brother(s) would serve him, "

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136974/discussion-between-aaron-and-salmononius2).